# how to set field name as file name bash/awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with 500 columns and I would need to split each column into a new file while printing $1 as common in all the files. Below is a sample file, and I managed to do this using the below bash/awk solution :

```
ID    F1    F2    F4    F4
aa    1    2    3    4 
bb    1    2    3    4
cc    1    2    3    4
dd    1    2    3    4

num=('1' '2' '3' '4')
for i in ${num[@]}; do awk -F "\t" -v col="$i" '{print $1,$col}' OFS="\t"        
Input.txt > ${i}.txt; done
```

which gives the required output as:

```
1.txt
ID    ID
aa    aa
bb    bb
cc    cc
dd    dd

2.txt
ID    F1
aa    1
bb    1
cc    1
dd    1

....
```

However, I could not track which file corresponds to which column as the output file name is the field number but not the field name. Could it be possible to write the header of the field as prefix to the output file name?

```
ID.txt
ID    ID
aa    aa
bb    bb
cc    cc
dd    dd

F1.txt
ID    F1
aa    1
bb    1
cc    1
dd    1
```

Comment: In principle, it can be done in a single pass in `awk`, but 500 columns could be a problem — you need to be able to open 500 files at minimum to do it in one pass (and my `ulimit -n` is 256 by default).  You may have to do multiple passes (say columns 2-99, 100-199, 200-299, 300-399, 400-499) or whatever.

Comment: read firs line and use is as index for `for` loop, user own counter to count columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, it seems like you're very close. Try

```
num=('1' '2' '3' '4')
for i in ${num[@]}; do
  echo "i=$i"
  awk -F "\t" -v col="$i" -v OFS="\t" '
    NR==1{fName=$(col+1)".out";next}
    {print $1,$(col+1) > fName}' data.txt
done   

1>cat F1.out
aa      1
bb      1
cc      1
dd      1

. . . .

1>cat F4.out
aa      4
bb      4
cc      4
dd      4
```

**Edit**

If you need to keep the headers as shown in your example output, just remove the `;next`.

---

**Edit 2**

If you have multiple column with the same name, you can append the data to same file by using `>> fName` instead. One word of warning with this technique. When you use `> fName`, this "restarts" the file each time you rerun your script. But when using `>>`, you will be appending to each file each time you run the script. That can cause problems for down-stream processes ;-) ... So you'd need to add code that cleans up your previous run of the script.

---

Here, we're relying on the fact that `awk` can also write output to a file, using `> fName` (where `fName` has been defined as the value of col(Num)+1 (to skip over the first column values).

And, if you were going to do this thousands of times a day, it would be worth further optimizing per comments above to have `awk` read the file once and create all the outputs from internal loops. But if you only need to do this a couple of times, then your 'use the tools of unix/linux to decompose the task into manageable parts' is perfectly appropriate.

IHTH

Comment: Don't miss to `close(fName)` after every line. Otherwise you may run out of file descriptors.

Comment: @hek2mgl : Hm.. my experience is that 1 `> fName` remains active only for the life of that `awk` invocation. As we're processing only one column at a time, doesn't that work?  Thanks and good luck to all.

Comment: If the column names a different that works. I a column can occur multiple times awk will keep that file open. If you have n different columns > file descriptors it will fail.

Comment: col+1? It looks like he wants to print the column of the inputted integer.

Comment: It needs to print every column to a file with $1 as standard first column in each file. i.e. file1 should have $1,$1, file2 should have $1,$2, file3 should have $1,$3 ..... with the header of each column as file name. i.e. using $1 header as file name to file1, $2 header as file name to file2....

Comment: @shellter Just noticed that there are duplicate header lines in the original input file, as shown in the modified input above with F4 twice. In this case there is only one F4.txt file in the output. Could it be possible to retain duplicate files?

Comment: so do you want a 2nd file named `F4_2`and `F2_...n`? Or can the data be appended to the original file?

Comment: yes!! by adding a prefix for the duplicates. Like in the above example F4 column is twice. The output can be written to F4_1.txt, F4_2.txt. It should not be appended as the content is different and only the header is same.

Comment: Thanks!! i would leave it accepted as it atleast works without duplicates. I could add some prefix for headers and then use the above solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all in one `awk` script. When processing the first line, put all the column headings in an array. Then when you process lines you write to the file names from that array in a loop.

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR == 1 { split($0, filenames) }
     {for (col = 1; col <= NF; col++) { 
        file= filenames[col] ".txt"; 
        print $1, $col >> file; 
        close(file) } }' Input.txt
```

Comment: Don't miss to `close($filenames[col])` after every line. Otherwise you may run out of file descriptors.

Comment: Most systems these days have thousands of descriptors, so it's not likely to be a problem, but I added it. I also changed to `>>`, is that necessary since I'm closing the file?

Comment: Most of files these days have millions of lines ;)

Comment: `awk -F'\t' 'NR == 1 { split($0, filenames) }{for (col = 1; col <= NF; col++) print $1, $col >> $filenames[col]".txt"; close($filenames[col]".txt")}' Genes.txt
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 NR == 1 { split($0, filenames) }{for (col = 1; col <= NF; col++) print $1, $col >> >>>  $filenames[col]".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: @hek2mgl The number of lines isn't an issue, the number of columns is. He says it's about 500.

Comment: @chas Sorry, I was thinking in PHP mode, and I accidentally had `$` before the `filenames` variable.